# Jquery/Php post without redirect

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am making a website that displays a list of hotels. I want to add a "favorite" button so that it stores that hotel with the user. From my understanding I need to use php/jquery based on some answers I saw on stackoverflow.

I have no experience with php/jquery. Absolutely none writing it or even adding some to my web page (this is the first website/web application I am trying to build.

After looking at a couple of stackoverflow answers on this topic I have checked out this website: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery--net-59
and attempted to click on the recommended link for newbies: 15 Resources to get you Started with jQuery From Scratch. 
but to no avail as the page is not found.

This is the html where I want to add the favorite button stored in "Bookmark for later". However, I know hypothetically even if my click worked I am not capturing the data of the specific hotel for which they clicked bookmark for later.

```
    {% for hotel in close_hotels %}
    <div id = "display_hotel">
        <p><font color="blue" size="2"><b> {{ hotel.name }} </font></b></p>
        <div id = "hotel_format">
        <div id = "favorite_form">
        <input id="bookmark" type="button" value="Bookmark for later!"
        onclick= "function()"/>
        </div>
```

This is my .js file. I tried following http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery--net-59 as best as I could, but recognized some differences. For example I am trying to capture information from a button(should I change this) instead of a form.
 I didn't bother with the form validation since it is just a button.

```
    $(function() }
//using a button to add hotel to favorites 
$(".button").click(function() {
    var hotel = $("input#bookmark").val();
//skipping form validation since no need -- using a button

});
});

    //next part of the tutorial
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "bin/process.php",
data: hotel,
success: function() {
    $('#contact_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
    $('#message').html("<h2>Hotel Favorited!</h2>")
    .hide()

    });
  }
        });
 return false;
```

Ultimately there are two things I am wondering. Is a button most appropriate for what I am seeking? If not, what else should I use, but if so how can I capture the hotel information with the PHP. Second of all as I am not familiar with php/jquery will the code work?

From my understanding this line should be able to capture the hotel name I want, but again I don't even think my button would even send the information.

```
    var hotel = $("input#bookmark").val();
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways to submit information to the server (your PHP code):

1. Using an HTML `<form>`
2. AJAX

I'm guessing you want to do it via AJAX since you're not sending typical form data. For that you would do something like this in jQuery:

```
var req = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://whatever.com/stuff",
    data: { "some_key": "some_value" }
});

req.done(function (response) {
    // code to run after the server handles your data and responds
});

req.fail(function(jq_xhr, text_status, error_thrown) {
    // if you want to handle errors ...
});
```

Comment: Is the 
var req....
data:{ "some_key": "some_value"}
 });

supposed to go in my html code? (in the hotel for loop)?

Comment: Put it inside a function, then call that function as the onclick event of your button. Hope this helps!

Comment: is url: "literally the url you're using it in" or is it the path to the ajax material?

Also, how does the {"some_key": "some_value" } capture the value I want it to from my original post (the first code block of HTML -- i want it to capture the hotel name). Do I need to add something in that first block of HTML and not just simply call the function?